# How to use JSON text object inside Pageview in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

In my flutter project I'm building a book app and I'm fetching the data from JSON. in order to make this I used `PageView.builder`. but when I do that it only display the text data separately showing each JSON object in Each page.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getAll(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Container(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    String file = "${quran_arabic['verses'][index]['text_uthmani'] as String} (${index})";
                    return Text(quran_arabic['verses'][index]['text_uthmani'] as String);
                  }),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

So what I want is to create pages and when the page is full it will pass to the next page until it finishes the text object. but I want all JSON texts to display continuously in a line.

the JSON example

```
{"verses":[{"id":6231,"verse_key":"114:1","text_uthmani":" قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ ٱلنَّاسِ"},{"id":6232,"verse_key":"114:2","text_uthmani":"مَلِكِ ٱلنَّاسِ"},{"id":6233,"verse_key":"114:3","text_uthmani":"إِلَـٰهِ ٱلنَّاسِ"},{"id":6234,"verse_key":"114:4","text_uthmani":"مِن شَرِّ ٱلْوَسْوَاسِ ٱلْخَنَّاسِ"},{"id":6235,"verse_key":"114:5","text_uthmani":"ٱلَّذِى يُوَسْوِسُ فِى صُدُورِ ٱلنَّاسِ"},{"id":6236,"verse_key":"114:6","text_uthmani":"مِنَ ٱلْجِنَّةِ وَٱلنَّاسِ"}]}
```

Comment: Do you want to show all `JSON` data in one page?

Comment: @PrinceSanjivy I've added it, I just posted the smallest text object. there is a long one as well.   Link is https://api.quran.com/api/v4/quran/verses/uthmani?chapter_number=2